# Why can't I typecast from char to int?

Tags: java, casting, char

For some reason, the following code does not work:

```
char cValue = '8';
int digits = (int)cValue;
```

It keeps giving some value of 5 or 7, or something along those lines.

I'm just curious why - I'm using `Character.getNumericValue(cValue);` instead.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you actually getting the value 56, which is the ASCII value of the character `'8'`?

Comment: You could just say `char cValue = 8;`. Then the cast should succeed as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* typecast char to int, and in fact you are. The binary representation of the character '8' is actually 56 (decimal). See [any ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the conversions. What you're looking for is parsing, not casting. [`getNumericValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28int%29) parses the char and gives you its numeric equivalent. Casting the char simply changes the type and leaves the pattern of bits the same. The bits are then interpreted according to the type of the variable they're associated with.

Answer (score 3):

A Java char is an unsigned 16-bit value.  When you cast one to int you get the Unicode value of the character.  The character '8' has a Unicode value of decimal 56.

getNumericValue is entirely different -- it gives you the MEANING of the character, if it's a character with a numeric meaning.